# Access jinja2 globals variables inside template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask app I'm building and I'm having issues accessing my jinja2 globals variables from within my templates, any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**__init__.py**

```
from config import *

...

#Initialize Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)

#Jinja2 global variables
jinja_environ = app.create_jinja_environment()
jinja_environ.globals['DANISH_LOGO_FILE'] = DANISH_LOGO_FILE
jinja_environ.globals['TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER'] = TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER

...
```

**config.py**

```
...

TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER = '../static/img/media_library/' #This is the location of the media_library relative to the templates directory
DANISH_LOGO_FILE = '100danish_logo.png'

...
```

**example template**

```
<p>{{ TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER }}</p>
```

In this instance, TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER prints out nothing to the template.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using Flask's `render_template` function here which is by default linked to the application's `jinja_env` attribute.

So try something like this,

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals['DANISH_LOGO_FILE'] = DANISH_LOGO_FILE
app.jinja_env.globals['TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER'] = TEMPLATE_MEDIA_FOLDER
```

Comment: @JoeyOrlando Glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works, but it gave me the pylint error

```
[pylint] E1101:Method 'jinja_env' has no 'globals' member
```

Do it this way to avoid the error:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_template_global(name='DANISH_LOGO_FILE', f=DANISH_LOGO_FILE)
```