# Flask: Method 'jinja_env' has no 'globals' member pylint(no-member)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, virtual-environment

How can i solve the error `Method 'jinja_env' has no 'globals' member in flask` ?
I'm using jinja2 version 2.11.2 & Flask version 1.1.2.
I want to call the method _build_auth_url inside my html templates.
app.py:

```
import uuid
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session 
import msal
import app_config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(app_config)
Session(app)


from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('index.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    auth_url = _build_auth_url(scopes=app_config.SCOPE, state=session["state"])
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=auth_url, version=msal.__version__)

@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    if request.args.get('state') != session.get("state"):
        return redirect(url_for("index"))  # No-OP. Goes back to Index page
    if "error" in request.args:  # Authentication/Authorization failure
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=request.args)
    if request.args.get('code'):
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            request.args['code'],
            scopes=app_config.SCOPE,  # Misspelled scope would cause an HTTP 400 error here
            redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()  # Wipe out user and its token cache from session
    return redirect(  # Also logout from your tenant's web session
        app_config.AUTHORITY + "/oauth2/v2.0/logout" +
        "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + url_for("index", _external=True))

@app.route("/graphcall")
def graphcall():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        app_config.ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
        ).json()
    return render_template('display.html', result=graph_data)


def _load_cache():
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(session["token_cache"])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        app_config.CLIENT_ID, authority=authority or app_config.AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=app_config.CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

def _build_auth_url(authority=None, scopes=None, state=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).get_authorization_request_url(
        scopes or [],
        state=state or str(uuid.uuid4()),
        redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))

def _get_token_from_cache(scope=None):
    cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result

app.jinja_env.globals.update(_build_auth_url=_build_auth_url)  # Used in template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My html templates:
Edit Profile

I tried the solutions at [Access jinja2 globals variables inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324090/access-jinja2-globals-variables-inside-template/50728800) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You did not include the code you are trying to use. This makes it very difficult to even start providing an answer. Please edit you question to include your code.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron Updated. It's a simple microsoft graph api cloned from the github repo but didn't work at a minimal configs.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows

app.jinja_env().globals.update(_build_auth_code_flow=_build_auth_code_flow)  # Used in template